# How do i override windows permissions for python file windows 10

Tags: python

This is my current code:

```
import psutil
count = 0
while count < 3000000000:
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name().lower() == 'chrome.exe':
            print(process)
            process.terminate()
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print('no')
            print(count)
```

its scanning all of he processes running. It then crashes when it scans:
' WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.Inpu...'

This is the windows service for the on screen keyboard. I tried to stop it running however it still runs. I was wondering if i could give my python file full permissions so this stops happening.

This is the error code from the terminal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_common.py", line 449, in wrapper
    ret = self._cache[fun]
AttributeError: _cache

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 679, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_common.py", line 452, in wrapper
    return fun(self)
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 766, in exe
    exe = cext.proc_exe(self.pid)
PermissionError: [WinError 24] The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect: '(originated from NtQuerySystemInformation)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/benmi/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/TerminateProgram.py", line 5, in 
    if process.name().lower() == 'chrome.exe':
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil__init__.py", line 630, in name
    name = self._proc.name()
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 750, in name
    return os.path.basename(self.exe())
  File "C:\Users\benmi\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 681, in wrapper
    raise convert_oserror(err, pid=self.pid, name=self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=8612)